# Is <input type="date"> working on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, html, jsp

I am new to HTML/CSS programming, and recently also started basics of JSP. I wanted to create a registration page accepting employee details like name, address etc. using JSP in an Eclipse (mars 2.0) like this (as on link)  :  [RegistrationPage.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcCJU.png)

Everything was OK but when I wanted to created a text field of 'date' type, eclipse is not recognizing it and marking it as a wrong attribute as (as on link) : [error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewyrC.png) It's supposed to accept date of birth of the employee in form of HTML date input box.

On pressing Ctrl + space they are providing the set of supported attributes but that does not include 'date' or 'mail' (for mail address input) attributes.

I want to know whether it's the feature of JSP or it has some thing to do with Eclipse itself? And any solution to the error on Eclipse only,  as I am asked to use Eclipse.

(There is no issue regarding browser support as I'm using chrome and  is working, as written on Notepad++)

Comment: Input type="data" is from HTML5. It's most likely that eclipse doesn't have HTML5 support or your page is not HTML5 friendly.

Comment: Can you or anyone write it in answer section? Only if you want...

Comment: I usually only write in answer section if I am 100% sure it works/is true.

Comment: Do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your page?

Comment: Oh. Recently I watched that my document was on html 4.01 and on changing the head it again worked. BTW thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Posted it as answer so it can be accepted and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="date">` is a HTML5 tag. Make sure your HTML page starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>` otherwise Eclipse doesn't know it's HTML5.